# What to do if there are collisions between directive/input names on an element?

Tags: angular

Since the directive names and input names share the same namespace in Angular (they are referred to as their sole names). What can I do if some of the names collide?

Example: I use two directives on the same element, the two directives have an input with the same name and I do not have a hand on the names because they are from external libraries.

Comment: Can you create a sample on stackblitz

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new directive with another name and with a class that simple extends the original, then you can bind to an @Input property.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective extends OriginalHighlightDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { super(el); }

  @Input('aliasInputColor') originalInputName: string;

}
```

---

Then you can use the aliasInputProperty:

```
<p appHighlight aliasInputColor="yellow">Highlight me!</p>
```